# Add azure service in Windows Runtime Component windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8.1, geofencing

I am developing a Location Based app. I am trying to submit location to azure service as a background task. But I can't add azure service to Runtime component as it doesn't have App class. It shows following message.

> Visual Studio was unable to find and update the App class in
>   'App.xaml.cs'.

Is there a way to submit current location to the azure service as a background task. Help me

Comment: which azure package are you using?

Comment: I am using Mobile Services Extension